# Highlight the selected feature with different colors

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-2

Is it possible to change the color of a selected feature in qgis 2.2.0 Valmiera? To highlight a feature I use:

```
aLayer.Select(feat.id())
box = vlayer.boundingBoxOfSelected()
qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().setExtent(box)
qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

But the selected featue is colored yellow. Is it possible to define a different color for this feature?

Comment: @Nathan W if you know the answer  please reply the question here please.